# Running Neuro-Programmer 3 with Wine

Tags: 11.04, wine

I bought Neuro-Programmer 3. Can anyone tell me how to run it on Ubuntu 11.04?
I installed wine and it said to:

> Please set registry key HKLM\software\microsoft.NETFramework\installroot to point to the .Net Framework install location

I am new to Ubuntu, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To access the registry type "wine regedit" without the quotes in terminal

Use Winetricks to install .Net if you have not already

Comment: "Thank's for your HELP,Your GREAT! Nero work's Great"

Answer (score 0):

There is also the free software Gnaural which does brainwave entrainment:

- http://gnaural.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/new-projects-fresh-labs-9
- http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/program-binaural-beats-brain-gnaural/