# How to resolve an error in WINE relating to .NET 2.0?

Tags: wine, winetricks

I'm trying to install both Neuroprogrammer 2 and 3 in [WINE](http://winehq.org).

At first I got the error:

```
Please set registry key HKLM\software\microsoft.NETFramework\installroot to point to the .Net Framework install location"
```

As described in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57851/running-neuro-programmer-3-with-wine?answertab=active#tab-top).

And so I installed .NET, but now I get an error that says:

```
Neuro-Programmer 2.exe - .NET Framework Initialization Error
To run this application, you first must install one of the following versions of the .NET Framework:
v2.0.50727
Contact your application publisher for instructions about obtaining the appropriate version of the .NET framework.
```

This is the error I get after I installed .NET 2.0. Therefore I decided to install .NET 2.0 SP2 and still got the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: This seems to be a bug with `wine` at the minute, as noted [here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19872), which discusses the same issues. I have also yet to overcome it with any workarounds- apart from Virtualbox running a full version of Windows. The current development version of `wine` (1.5.19) also has the same problems.